# JQuery removeClass function not working on a child element

Tags: jquery, find, children, removeclass

Very simple question. Why is this not working:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    //$(this).removeClass('nw_hidden');    //this works
    var el = $(this).find('.nw_div')[0];
    el.removeClass('nw_hidden');           //this not
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `el` is a DOMelement, not a jQuery object. Try:

```
$(el).removeClass('nw_hidden');
```

or else make `el` a jQuery object to begin with:

```
var el = $(this).find('.nw_div');
```

or possibly

```
var el = $(this).find('.nw_div').first();
```

Comment: hm... this is how I learned DOMelement and a jquery object are not the same thing :) ... thanks